# pureio pure-u-1-2 not aligning side by side

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have this exact code, but still the divs are stacking over each other. I've looked up similar questions but in all of them there are obvious reasons for why the divs are not side by side. I just cannot figure out why this should not work

```
      <div class="pure-g-r">
        <div class="pure-u-1-2"><h2>hello</h2></div>
        <div class="pure-u-1-2"><h2>hello</h2></div>
      </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It works with "pure-g" but not with the responsive grid "pure-g-r"

Comment: I figured it out. Looks like the "-r" no longer exists in pure...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like pure has removed the "grid-g-r" part, so "grid-g" will do iff I specify the screen resolution.

This works:

```
<div class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2"><h2>hello</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2"><h2>hello</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```